# Sublime Text 2 - Vim like search highlight in Command mode?

Tags: vim, sublimetext2

In Vim if I hit SHIFT * over *fooBar*, or type

```
    /fooBar
```

all instances of 'fooBar' in the file will be highlighted and I can navigate through them using the N key.

How do I get this highlighting in Sublime Text 2 with Vintage enabled and VintageEx plugin installed (**not** Insert mode using ALT F3)?

Comment: Sublime text highlights all matches for `/foo` in command mode for me... The only custom setting I seem to have is `"vintage_start_in_command_mode": true`

Comment: Yes, but if I move the cursor away from 'foo', all highlighting will disappear for me.  Does it stay for you?  How do you keep the highlighting like when searching in Vim?

Comment: You can map e.g. some function key to `let @/='\<<C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR>\>'`, i.e. the word will be "search highlighted" but no search is done. But the "latest search" will then be your current word, so using e.g. `n` will find that word instead of your "real last search". Perhaps that is not helping.

Comment: @244an, not sure how or where to implement this.  Which Sublime Text 2 file do I add that to?

Comment: Sorry, I thought sublime text 2 was a plugin to vim, let me know when you read this and I will delete my comments

Comment: @244an no worries.  Just looking for a way to do match highlighting in ST2 like in Vim.

Answer (score 3):

In SublimeText 2, using / to start and type your search, hold down command and hit g to cycle through the highlighted results.  Hit enter to go into visual mode on the result you selected.

Comment: Thanks but I'm on Windows, Command G is the same as Alt F3, which is not the behavior I am looking for if you check the orig post. http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html

Comment: Whoops... missed that part.  :)

Comment: Is there a way to make command-g the default, and can I make all results highlighted rather than just one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

I am also a heavy vimer who want try press N to jump to next searching word,as well as I am looking for one plugin which should done as your expect in the past,but I have changed my habit with use `shift+enter` or `minimap to scroll` instead of press N to jump, It works effective for me now.

NOTICE:
Don't press `ENTER` when finished press `/foo` with Vintage plugin on,this well stop draw outline.

Answer (score 0):

The [Vintageous](https://github.com/guillermooo/Vintageous) package highlights all `/` instances by default.